# Internet Explorer 10 box-shadow size

Tags: internet-explorer-9, size, conditional-statements, css, internet-explorer-10

Normally I don't bother the small differences in the rendering of box-shadows in different browsers, but in this case the box-shadow size is kind of important. IE9 and IE10 render a [smaller box-shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982687/css3-box-shadow-blur-in-ie9). Explorer 9 can be fixed with a little larger box shadow using conditional comments, but IE10 appears to have eliminated support for conditional comments. Is there a way of correcting the IE10 box-shadow size and make it a little larger like safari, chrome, firefox?

I know it's a little similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-ie10-for-certain-situations) but maybe someone have a trick for box-shadows size that works in IE9/10 or IE10 only.

For the record - this is a responsive site, and the box-shadow in question is applied to a li element with percentage width (for navigation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. There are several ie10 hacks out there, but this one is `CSS only` and targets both `IE9` and `IE10`. It is called the `@media Zero Hack`. You can find this one and other ie10 hacks at http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/

```
.navigation ul li a {
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #2d231c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #2d231c;
  -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #2d231c;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #2d231c;
}
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    /* IE9 and IE10 rule sets go here */
.navigation ul li a {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px #3a312a;
 }
}
```

It uses a parsing bug in `IE9/10`. If this bug is fixed in `IE11` this will also be future proof. I don't know how `IE11` will handle `box-shadow`.
More on [moving IE specific CSS into @media blocks](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/)